# Use the Euclidean Algorithmn to find $\gcd(56,38)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use the Euclidean Algorithmn to find the gcd, $g$, of $56$ and $38$. Then find integers $x$ and $y$ such that $56x +38y=g$

$a=qb +r$

$56= 1(38) + 18$

gfc $56= 1,2,4,7,8,14, 28,56$
gfc $38= 1,2,19,38$

gfc of $56$ and $38$ is $2$. I know it is $2$, but by using Euclidean algorithm??

could you show me the step by step?

Comment: Dear amie/jake/tyler: Why are you making multiple accounts?

Answer (score 4):

You started correct. The euclidian algorithm works as follows: Divide one number by the other, then the other number by the remainder and so forth until the remainder is zero. The last non zero remainder is the gcd. Then backwards you will get a representation for the gcd.

We have in your example: 
\begin{align*}
  56 &= 1 \cdot 38 + 18\\
  38 &= 2 \cdot 18 + 2\\
  18 &= 2 \cdot 9
\end{align*}
hence $\gcd(56, 38) = 2$, backwards, we have 
\begin{align*} 
  2 &= 38 - 2 \cdot 18\\
    &= 38 - 2 \cdot (56 - 38)\\
    &= 38 - 2 \cdot 56 - 2\cdot (-38)\\
    &= 3 \cdot 38 - 2 \cdot 56.
\end{align*}

Comment: how did you get 3 * 38 - 2*56??

Comment: @tyler I added a line, ok now?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use the matrix method. It works as follows:

You start off by writing an augmented identity matrix, with the two numbers whose $\gcd$ you want to find in the augmented bit, i.e:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & & 56 \\ 0 & 1 & & 38 \end{pmatrix}.$$

You then apply row operations to both sides until you get a $0$, so we would first do row $1$ subtract row $2$, which gives

$$\pmatrix{1 & -1 & & 18 \\ 0 & 1 & & 36}$$

Then we do row $2$ subtract $2 \times $ row $1$ which gives

$$\pmatrix{1 & -1 & & 36 \\ -2 & 3 & & 0}.$$

What the last line shows is that as $-2$ comes first, we related it to the number we put at the top of our augmented matrix (i.e $56$) and so we can then say that the $3$ goes to the $38$ and so we end up having

$$(3 \times 38) + (-2 \times 56) = 0$$

which is a check and we see that it is correct. We can now check to see if $3$ and $2$ divide both $56$ and $38$ and from here we see that the gcd is $2$.

This matrix method is quite useful when you want to calculate things like the modulo multiplicative inverse of large numbers.

Comment: love this method!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the other answers is wrong, but it's possibly easier to apply Euclid's algorithm in this form:

**Euclid's algorithm:** For all integers $n,m$ we have:

1. $\gcd(n,m) = \gcd(m,n)$;
2. $\gcd(n,m) = \gcd(n,m - n)$
3. If $n \mid m$, then $\gcd(n,m) = n$.

The algorithm then works by simply subtracting one argument in the $\gcd(,)$ from the other repeatedly until one of them divides the other, and declaring that to be the answer.  Thus, for your problem:

$$\begin{align}
 \gcd(56,38)
 &= \gcd(38, 56) = \gcd(38,56 - 38) = \gcd(38,18) \\
 &= \gcd(18,38) = \gcd(18,38 - 18) = \gcd(18,20) \\
 &= \gcd(18,20 - 18) = \gcd(18,2) \\
 &= \gcd(2,18) = 2
\end{align}$$

This may appear to take longer than using formal long division as in martini's answer, but in fact, the repeated subtractions (see for example the series of reductions from $\gcd(18,38)$ to $\gcd(18,2)$) are the same as figuring out what the quotient and remainder are (in this case, $2$ and $2$ respectively).  You can do this process more or less mechanically this way, since it requires absolutely no thinking except to check whether one number divides the other.

Comment: Another good method, but it doesn't help with the last bit of the question, the writing it in the form $56a + 38b = g$ bit. But still, if the numbers aren't too big and you just need to find the gcd, this is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500)

$\quad\begin{eqnarray}
56\, =  \ \ 1\cdot 56 + 0\cdot 38\\
38\, =  \ \ 0\cdot 56 + 1\cdot 38\\
18\, = \ \ 1\cdot 56 - 1\cdot 38\\
2\,  = -2\cdot 56 + 3\cdot 38
\end{eqnarray}$